# R: conditional matrix filling with for loops through rows and column indices

Tags: r, for-loop

I am an R beginner and I know this is quite basic, I'm sorry, but I couldn't find my own way through this by just following the documentation and similar threads.

I am trying to fill an empty matrix `mat2` using conditional statements and looping through both the rows and columns of another dataframe of the same dimensions `ixj` i am using as a reference matrix, called `mat`. In this example `mat` is also my "source" of values for `mat2`, but that is not entirely true in my real problem, nor it is relevant for the sakes of solving this. I have been trying to make it work like this...

```
mat

 1  -2   3
 2  -4   6
 3  -6   9
-4   8  -12


mat2 = matrix(0L, nrow = nrow(mat), ncol = ncol(mat))

for (i in nrow(mat)) {
  for (j in ncol(mat)){
    if (mat[i,j] >= 0) {
      mat2[i,j] = 0
      }
    else {
      mat2[i,j] = mat[i,j]
    }
  }
}
```

...which leads to...

```
mat2

0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0  -12
```

...not quite what I was looking for.

I am more interested in the syntax of my for loops and conditional cell assignment, apart from that this is just dummy code: I don't need to replace values in `mat` but create a new matrix and fill it with values following specific conditions and equations.

Nevertheless, I don't know what I am doing wrong, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What should be the output?

Comment: The problem with your loops is simply that you are only iterating over a single value.  Try `for (i in 1:nrow(mat))` instead of `for (i in nrow(mat))`.

Comment: Yes, @AndrewGustar that is correct, the loops were broken, but in R, you don't need to make that awkward  loop within a loop just to operate over a matrix, since a matrix is just a vector with dimension attributes.

Comment: @AndrewGustar how the hell did I miss that?

Comment: May I ask why you are using this construction of "index and replace" in 2 loops? Typically, when you find yourself writing loops like this in R, you should consider if there is a vectorized way of solving the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As AndrewGustar pointed out in a comment to the original post, there was a rather dumb mistake in my loop syntax. I corrected it, and it works, the correct syntax being

```
for (i in 1:nrow(mat)) {
  for (j in 1:ncol(mat)){
```

instead of

```
for (i in nrow(mat)) {
  for (j in ncol(mat)){
```

which caused my code to be "looping" over only the last pair of index values for the rows and columns, namely `(nrow(mat), ncol(mat))` or `(4, 3)`.

The correct output is

```
mat2

    0   -2    0
    0   -4    0
    0   -6    0
   -4    0  -12
```

Answer (score 0):

Forget all the loops:

```
mat <- c(1,  -2,   3,
         2,  -4,   6,
         3,  -6,   9,
         -4,   8,  -12)
dim(mat) <- c(4, 3)

mat2 <- mat
mat2[mat2 >= 0] <- 0
```

Comment: that is not quite what I was looking for, I'm sorry, I thought I was clear enough in my question